# Android GoogleMaps MapView with Search bar

Tags: android, android-mapview, placeautocompletefragment

I have a Fragment containing a MapView object and would like to equip it with a searchbar.
I found Google Maps documentation on [PlaceAutoCompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment), however this only seems to work with a MapFragment, not a MapView.

Anyone know if it is possible to use this on a MapView object as well?
Thanks!

Comment: you can use 
Place Picker by google and when clicking on place in list you will get lat-long. now you can use this lat-long to show place in MapView.

Comment: is there a way to combine the place picker with the markers of my app and also to use it within my current fragment and not as a new activity? Cant really find much documentation

Comment: you need to remove Map fragment from your xml layout and put MapView and placepicker in that xml layout. so here you can get the both place picker and mapview both in same xml layout